# probability that a string of length $m$ over the alphabet of length $n$ will have exactly $k$ as the number of most frequent elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a string over the alphabet $A$ ($A$ has $n$ different characters). Now I have a string of length $m$ which can have duplicated characters. For example a string `abcccbbad` has 2 `a`, 3 `b`, 3 `c`, 1 `d` and I am interested in the number of occurrences of the most frequent character (in my case it is `3`)

Is there a way to find the probability that a string of length $m$ over the alphabet of length $n$ will have exactly $k$ as the number of most frequent elements?

---

Here is my rudimentary attempt.

The probability will be $\frac{N_{strings\  with \ k \ as \ most \ freqent }}{N_{all\ strings}}$. Number of all strings is easy to get: $n^m$, but to calculate the number of strings that have exactly $k$ as the number of most frequent elements is hard for me.

If $k = 1$ it is just $n \cdot (n-1) \cdot ... \cdot (n-m + 1)$ and therefore for $k=n-1$ will be number of all strings minus number where $k=1$.

But I fail to get a formula even for $k=2$, not to mention anything further.

Comment: Let $a$ be the coefficient of  $x^{m}$ in $(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^k)^n-(1+x+\dots+x^{k-1})^n$. What you want is $a/\binom{m+n-1}{m}$.

Comment: @dREaM thank you for a reply. It kind of makes sense to me that you take $a$ from generating functions, but it is unclear to me why do you divided by combinations with replacements and not by $n^m$. Also is there a hope to get an easier formula?

Comment: Sorry, my formula was flawed.

Comment: More generalized form: the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ labelled objects into $k$ labelled subsets, each of which has maximum $r$ elements.